# Get too much time to execute converted user control from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I upgraded vb6 project to vb.net.
Conversion of 3 user controls from vb6 to vb.net have done
Some converted code contains code like

```
VB6.TwipsToPixelsY(LedHeight)
MyBase.Width = VB6.TwipsToPixelsX(VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(LedCol(0).Width) + 15)
```

The converted project takes **too much time to load** than previous vb6 project..
What manual changes to the code should be done or is there any other option.
Is it due to vb6 to vb.net conversion

Comment: The code sample you used above is doing nothing more than setting MyBase.Width equal to 1 pixel more than LedCol(0).Width.

Comment: Time to load where? In the IDE (Note that Visual Studio 200X is very different to VB6) or at run time?

Answer (score 1):

That can't be the only problem. That code should execute almost instantaneously. I suggest putting break points throughout the area where you think performance is a problem and see if you can narrow down where the problem exists.

In my experience, converted code may run slightly slower at first until you correct the conversion oddities.